# Задача не выполняет никаких действий. Подскажите, почему?

Tags: pascal

Дано n натуральных чисел. Определить, есть ли среди них число X. Почему программа не выполняет никаких действий после ввода данных?

```
var n,x,k,s,i:integer;
begin
  s:=0;
  readln(n,x);
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    readln(k);
    if k=x then 
      s:=s+1
  end;
  if s=0 then 
    writeln ('нет')
  else writeln ('да');
end.
```

Comment: а вы числа правильно ввели? по 1 в строке и так далее?

Comment: В программе ошибок нет. Покажите, что Вы вводите? Может проблема в том, что программа завершается и Вы не видите ответа?

Comment: Задача написана корректно. Ошибка, скорее всего, в действиях пользователя. Добавьте перед последним end. строчку readln; чтобы программа не завершалась сразу, и вы увидели ответ.

Comment: спасибо все получилось